# DateFormatString not works after upgrade version NewtonSoft Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I upgrade my NewtonSoft Json of 7.00 to 8.00 and my function not working anymore,How can I use DataFormatString in new version of NewtonSoft.Json?

code example follows:

```
 public static T DeserializarJson<T>(string json)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings set = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    set.DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    var objeto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, set);

    return objeto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, what's the error?

Comment: can you post what you `using` section looks like in your .cs file header..? also if you are using `nuget` to get the newer version of the assembly, make sure that the packages.config and the web.config or app.config file have the correct settings for your version of `Newtonsoft.Json` for example i am using ver6 

`<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>`

Comment: Sorry he was in wrong version, the version was 4.00.. I will

Answer (score 1):

It was wrong version, the version  returned to 4:00 because the package nugget had worked wrong for this dll.

After I remove the line from app.config and dll and reinstall the code returned to work.